# Need help looking into IndexOutOfRange Exception for my Audio Manager script

Tags: unity, c#, audio

basically, its as the title says. I am trying to build a brick breaker game in Unity2D, and I have found myself unable to play the death sound effect (played whenever a brick breaks).

```
using UnityEngine;

public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update

    public AudioClip[] sounds;
    public AudioSource[] sauce;
    public GameObject brick;

    void Awake()
    {
        foreach(AudioClip sound in sounds) {
            AudioSource source = this.gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
            source.clip = sound;

        }

        sauce = GetComponents<AudioSource>();            
    }

    void Start() {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
       Debug.Log(sauce[0]);
    }

    public void BrickDeath() {
        sauce[0].Play();
    }
}
```

This is my audiomanager script, the Debug.Log statement in the Update() function clearly shows that there is an AudioSource object in the array.

[image]
However, the strange thing is when I reference the AudioManager game object in my Brick game object as so

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Brick : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame updates
    public int health;
    public Sprite brokenBrick;
    SpriteRenderer sr;
    public GameObject audioManager;
    AudioManager manager;
    private void Start()
    {
        sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        manager = audioManager.GetComponent<AudioManager>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {   
        if (health < 15) {
            sr.sprite = brokenBrick;
        } if (health <= 0) {
            manager.BrickDeath();
            Death();
        }  
    }

    private void Death() {
        Destroy(this.gameObject,1f);
    }

   
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {

        health -= 10;

    }
}
```

it gives me this error

```
IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
AudioManager.BrickDeath () (at Assets/Scripts/AudioManager.cs:43)
Brick.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Brick.cs:26)
```

This is the setup of my inspector for the AudioManager
[image]

and this is for my brick object.

[image]

Solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance and sorry for the rather poor formatting.

Comment: Why is there an brick on your audiomanager?

Comment: @Zibelas earlier i tried referencing it so that I could get the script component of the Brick and access it's health property, so I can play the sound upon death. it appears I have forgotten to remove it.